# Graph Theory: Splitting a Graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

I have this problem. I have a graph of n nodes that I want to split into two subgraphs of x nodes and n-x nodes subject to the constraint that the number of remaining edges is maximized (or minimizing the number of edges that are cut).

Not sure if that makes sense. Not a graph theory person but this is the abstract version of my problem. What algorithms should I look at that might help me?

This is NOT a homework problem. Interesting problem though I think!

I plan on implementing in C.

Comment: Is x a parameter or you are just looking for 2 sub graphes?  If x is not a parameter, wouldn't you just look for the node with the least number of edges and cut it out of the graph?

Comment: yes.. sorry I should have made that more clear. Say x is 10 and the total nodes is 25. I want two graphs, one with 10 nodes and one with 15..by "cutting" the least number of edges.

Comment: Definitely an interesting problem.  Actually my first assumption about looking for a single node is wrong - I came up with a graph where that isn't true.  Good luck finding a solution!

Comment: Note what you are describing will not necessarily have a unique solution.  Imagine a 4 node graph arranged in a simple square, and you choose x as 2.  Cutting the top and bottom edges is not obviously better than cutting the left and right edges.  You will either need to formally define a priority of edge cutting (perhaps based on node order), or otherwise manage the fact that there will be a set of equally correct solutions.

Comment: If x was not fixed this would be a minimum cut problem and its solution is using max flow. I have never seen the problem with having x fixed and I am not familiar with an approach for that.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with the programming language you plan to implement this, no? Removing the C tag.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The special case where x = n - x is called the minimum bisection problem and is NP-hard. This makes your problem NP-hard as well. There are several heuristics described in the Wikipedia article on [graph partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_partition), including local search (e.g., start with a random cut and repeatedly swap pairs of vertices that decrease the size of the cut) and spectral methods (e.g., compute and threshold the second eigenvector). If n is small, integer programming is also a possibility.

Comment: Yikes. Probably too advanced for a non-computer scientist. Might be better off just using a genetic algorithm if x is small? Just take a bunch of random sets of x=10 and, for the cases where the graph is partitioned into exactly two parts, take the top 10% in terms of minimum cuts, and then mutate those for a bunch of generations? Do you think that could be effective? Or, does it depend completely on the data-set. I guess I may as well try it.

Comment: Local search is pretty easy to implement: just start with a cut and try to improve it by making small changes. Computing eigenvectors isn't too bad but does require some math knowledge. Integer programming is hard, but there are free libraries. I'm not fond of genetic algorithms for combinatorial problems, but they might be better than local search if you're willing to throw enough cycles at them.

Comment: Ya actually I was able to write a simple branch and bound algorithm that works effectively for my particular problem... I'm going to accept your answer though because its clearly right even though I don't quite get it. I'm gonna read into eigenvectors for the sake of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a depth first search over nodes.  We assign nodes one at a time and count the number of cuts so far.  If that number exceeds the best solution's number, then we abort this one and backtrack.

1. Given the full set of nodes S, let P and P' be setsuts of nodes, initially empty, and K by the number of cut edges, initially 0.
2. Let S*, K* be the best known solution and its number of cut edges, with K* initially infinity.
3. Pick a node N to start with and assign it to S.
4. For each unassigned node M:

   1. Assign M to S', and add the number of edges from M to nodes in S to K.
   2. If K > K*, then no solution based on this one will beat the best, so assign M to S.
   3. If |S| > X, then the set has grown too big; backtrack.
   4. Otherwise, recurse from 4.
5. If all nodes are assigned and K < K*, then let S* = S and K* = K.

I've been imagining this as a Prolog-type algorithm, but doing it in C shouldn't be too hard.  Backtracking just means unassigning the last assigned node.

Answer (score 0):

basically you are looking at a modified version of the min-cut problem.

One way would be to modify [karger's algorythm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karger%27s_algorithm)
In Karger's algo you contract vertices along random edges until you end up with only two vertices, the remaining edges represent the cut. Since it's random you just do this many times and keep the solution with the least edges in the cut.

In the modified version once a vertex has been collapsed x times you could stop collapsing  and count outgoing edges (these would be the the cut in your case), do it a suitable amount of times, and you have a solution. The tricky part is figuring out how many times to repeat the calculations to increase confidence to a satisfactory limit

Comment: min cut problems don't have fixed `x` [number of vertices in one of side of the cut], and have specific `source` and `sink`. If you have a reduction in mind to min-cut problem - please add it to your answer.

Comment: I think some kind of modification to Karger's could solve this problem. There's no sink and source in min cut problems per se, it's just that some algorythms reduce the problem to a max flow one. I'll edit the answer if i can come up with a good modification to karger's that handles the fixed x case (there's one obvious way, but not sure it gives correct results)